# installing websocket with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to install websocket on nodejs with npm I am getting following error..
I am installing it on windows.

```
npm install websocket

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'websocket@1.0.3' ]
2 info using npm@1.1.32
3 info using node@v0.8.0
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose config file C:\Users\tasleem\.npmrc
6 verbose config file C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\etc\npmrc
7 verbose config file C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc
8 verbose read json C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\package.json
9 verbose read json C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\package.json
10 verbose read json C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\package\package.json
11 verbose read json C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\websocket-1.0.6\package.json
12 verbose read json C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\package.json
13 verbose cache add [ 'websocket@1.0.3', null ]
14 silly cache add name=undefined spec="websocket@1.0.3" args=["websocket@1.0.3",null]
15 verbose parsed url { pathname: 'websocket@1.0.3',
15 verbose parsed url   path: 'websocket@1.0.3',
15 verbose parsed url   href: 'websocket@1.0.3' }
16 silly cache add name="websocket" spec="1.0.3" args=["websocket","1.0.3"]
17 verbose parsed url { pathname: '1.0.3', path: '1.0.3', href: '1.0.3' }
18 verbose addNamed [ 'websocket', '1.0.3' ]
19 verbose addNamed [ '1.0.3', '1.0.3' ]
20 verbose url raw websocket/1.0.3
21 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './websocket/1.0.3' ]
22 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket/1.0.3
23 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket/1.0.3
24 error Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
24 error     at errnoException (net.js:781:11)
24 error     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:772:19)
24 error  { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT] code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }
25 error You may report this log at:
25 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
25 error or email it to:
25 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
26 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
27 error command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "websocket@1.0.3"
28 error cwd C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs
29 error node -v v0.8.0
30 error npm -v 1.1.32
31 error syscall connect
32 error code ETIMEDOUT
33 error message connect ETIMEDOUT
34 error errno ETIMEDOUT
35 error ETIMEDOUT errno
36 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Or I have got the WebSocket package , could someone tell where to extract this inside nodejs folder?

Comment: any reason why you would not just rely on socket.io to take care of web sockets for you?

Comment: No reason as such.. but I have not googled enough on Socket.io.
Can it be integrated with nodejs?

Comment: There are many reasons, for example Socket.IO does not scale well. As for the question: it seems that this is a network problem.

Comment: so WebSocket is better than socket.io?
@freakish Can you tell where to extract the WebSocket folder inside nodejs?

Comment: Not necessarly better - it depends on your needs. For example I use ws module. If you have WebSocket package, then you need to find a node_modules folder and extract it there. You may create one in your app's folder, if you wish to hold the library locally there. See this: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/modules.html#loading_from_node_modules_Folders

Comment: @freakish - I'm not disputing what you are saying - can you share some test results or perhaps point to repeatable test results online - it would probably help a number of people who visit this post

Comment: @alihaider https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/686 I've experienced **exactly** the same problems. Although I do not think that altering the source code (like those guys from the link) is a good way to handle things.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a connection problem between your site and [the NPM registry](http://registry.npmjs.org). Try first to connect to [NPM registry](http://registry.npmjs.org) in a browser, you should have the same error.

Check your network connectivity, you can also try to `ping registry.npmjs.org`.

Comment: It is opening in browser but from command prompt it is telling timed out.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have a proxy to access to the Internet?

Comment: No i don't have. I don't know whats wrong..
Ok apart from that. If I have a WebSocket package where should I put it to use?

Comment: @Fahad - are you able to install anything using npm with the current versions of node/npm at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

a "npm up -g" cannot hurt either..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can help you.
I was using nodejs on windows via. Cygwin and when I tried making javascripts with websockets I had problems with the standard node installation - it was too old, I then tried to install a new version of node from inside Cygwin, however this was NOT possible, so I proceeded to install it using "node-v0.10.24-x64.msi" which can be downloaded from http://nodejs.org/download/

After download I then copied manually all contents from folder nodejs to cygwin /usr/local/bin

In order to install ws (websockets) then npm is needed and for that you need the newest version - after copying manually whole folder nodejs, then you can start cygwin and write following:

`node -v`

it should write something like this :

$ node -v

v0.10.24

now you can procede with following:

`$ cd /usr/local/bin/node_modules/npm/bin`

`$ node npm-cli.js install ws`

`$ node npm-cli.js install websockets`

the npm-cli.js  is a command line interface version of npm, made in javascript and nodejs can parse it, so now ws module should be installed

-- NOTE it is very important that you copy or move the folder "node_modules" after the installation to following place :

cygwin/home/ --your user-- /node_modules

Otherwise your javascript projects will not beable to see the installed modules - it is actually strange why, but I have no answer for that - I just made a copy and then it worked

I hope you can use this answer

Comment: one extra thing - if you are considering using standard websocket with javascript, then make sure you follow HyBi-10 or later, since HyBi-00 is faulty - it is however in use in old mobile phones browsers - I unfortunately could not get basic connection working with HyBi-00, due to security reasons and I guess that is why HyBi-00 is discontinued and HyBi-10 is newest standard

Answer (score 0):

> **Step1 : Set up  server**
>   Express takes the role of HTTP server, serving HTML file and wiring Websocket service

```
var express = require('express')
var ws = require('./ws')
var app = express()
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendfile(__dirname + '/ws.html');
})
app.listen(3000, function () {
   console.log('app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

> **Step2 : Set up Client** 
>   websocket client is a browser supported object.
>
> Below is goind to introduce 3 importand fucntion:
>
> ws.onopen : emmited when connected
>   ws.send : sending a send event to websocket server
>   ws.onmessage : event emmited when receiving message

```
    <script>
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:40510');
    // event emmited when connected
    ws.onopen = function () {
        console.log('websocket is connected ...')
        // sending a send event to websocket server
        ws.send('connected')
    }
    // event emmited when receiving message 
    ws.onmessage = function (ev) {
        console.log(ev);
    }
</script>
```

> For ur reference : https://hackernoon.com/nodejs-web-socket-example-tutorial-send-message-connect-express-set-up-easy-step-30347a2c5535